# MS ACESS :restrict numbers of rows in ms access query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two tables i want to select some specific numbers of records from table 1. the count of records must be equal to value mention in table 2.

Table1
[image: Table 1]

Table2
[image: Table 2]

Number of records in output must be equal to qty column in table 2. is it possible using access or i have to use VBA.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *Cartesian* (multiplying) query:

```
SELECT 
    Products.*, 
    Barcodes.*
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Tens]+[Ones] AS Factor, 
        10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10) AS Tens, 
        Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10) AS Ones
    FROM 
        MSysObjects AS Uno, 
        MSysObjects AS Deca) AS F, 
    Products 
INNER JOIN 
    Barcodes
    ON Products.Barcode = Barcodes.Barcode
WHERE 
    F.Factor <= Barcodes.Qty;
```

This will create up to 100 labels per barcode.

Answer (score 0):

`"Top N"` limits the number of records.

`"Select Top 5 Barcode, Brand, Qty FROM Table1 WHERE Barcode = 4044228585563"`

Use Union to Select the Top N record from multiple Items

```
Select Top 5 Barcode, Brand, Qty FROM Table1 WHERE Barcode = 4044228585563
Union
Select Top 5 Barcode, Brand, Qty FROM Table1 WHERE Barcode = 4029045653046
```

Comment: NO top n records will return only 1 items result, i need multiple items, as you see in table 2 there are different items and their qty is also different.

Comment: @gagankakkar you would have to create a `Select Query` for each item and use `Union` or `Union All` to combine the records.

Comment: how can i do it using vba macro as i want to do it using programming not every time a person need to create new query.

Comment: Create a function that takes a `Barcode` and `Qty` parameter and returns a single `Select Statement`.  Then you will have to loop through Table 2 and concatenate the  `Select Statement` for each `Barcode`.  If you have performance problems or Query length exceeds the limit (+64K characters) , you should consider creating a temp table to hold the data,  You would need to run an insert query for each `Barcode` but it would probably be much faster.

Comment: i create a VBA macro and achieved the desired result, thanks for your support.